# Why partial view not rendering in the same page? (ASP.NET MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've faced a problem for partial view displaying.

```
    //This is Controller Action 
//_AcademicInfo is the Partial view name
public PartialViewResult GetAcademicInfo(int empId)
        {
            var acad = _academicService.GetAcademinByEmp(empId);
            return PartialView("_AcademicInfo", acad);
        }

<!--Parent/caller page cshtml code-->

@Ajax.ActionLink(
            "Academic Details",
            "GetAcademicInfo",
            "Employee", new {empId = Model.Id},
            new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "AcademicDetails", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter}
            )
```

```
 <!--This is partial view cshtml-->
@model IEnumerable<Hik.PhoneBook.Data.Entities.Academic>

<div id="result">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Degree Name</th>
            <th>Passing Year</th>
            <th>CGPA</th>
            <th>Institute</th>
        </tr>


        @foreach (var acad in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => acad.DegreeName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => acad.PassingYear)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => acad.CGPA)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => acad.Institute)</td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>

</div>
```

As because, I need to get the partial view by a Link clicking, not by rendering directly like `@Html.Partial("_AcademicInfo", Model.Academic)`. Thats why I've used Ajax.ActionLink. Whenever I click on "Academic Details" link, its executing the accurate result. But unfortunately its not displaying in the same page. Its going to appear in another page. (Its MVC 4)

**What should I need to change to render the partial view in the same page?**

Comment: That because you have not included the relevant scripts - you need to include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

Comment: Yup I've used that already @section scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

Comment: Then you possibly have duplicates or other scripts out of order (`jquery` needs to be first). Edit your question to show all the scripts in the view

Comment: @sharmoon You'll also need to provide either a more complete example of the "parent" view, or include the rendered HTML.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yup u r corrcet. My "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" was set before main jQuery loading. But I cant mark your answer as correct answer coz there is no 'Right/Correct' sign besides ur answer.

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yup u r corrcet. My "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" was set before main jQuery loading. n thats why it wasnt fire. **But I cant mark your answer as correct answer coz there is no 'Right/Correct' sign besides ur answer. what to do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are redirecting to a new page rather than staying on the same page, it means that `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not loaded and `@Ajax.ActionLink()` falls back to a normal link.

Either you have either

1. not included the script
2. have the scripts in the wrong order (`jquery{version}.js` must come
   first)
3. You have duplicate scripts

Answer (score 0):

Try using JQuery Ajax to load the partial view into the Div on the page on button/link click instead.

```
var jsondata = { Id: iddata };

$.ajax({
    url: "/Controllername/GetAcademicInfo",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: jsondata,
    success: function (response) {
        $("#divId").html(response);

    }

});
```

Please note that this is just a sample code for giving you an idea.

Hope that helps!

Comment: OP is returning a partial view, not json, so it need to be `dataType: "html",`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use jquery's .load() function ? Like this.

```
$("divId").load('@url.action("getacademicInfo")', {empId : 4});
```

https://api.jquery.com/load/