# How to fill an empty <div> with a partial view using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using Visual Studio 2013, .Net 4.5, MVC and Visual Basic.  I am trying to render a partial view in an empty div of another view using jQuery and Ajax.  My script is running successfully in that on the drop down list change, my partial view is rendered, but instead of it rendering in a div on the same view, it renders on it's own page.

Main View:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-sm" type="button" id="dropDownSelectBuilding" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                        aria-expanded="true">

                    <span class="selection"></span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labeledby="dropDownSelectBuilding">
                    @For Each item In Model
                        Dim currentItem = item
                        @<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/LocationSelect/SelectFloor"
                                                    >@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem)</a></li>
                    Next
                </ul>
            </div>
            @section Scripts
                <script>
                    $('#dropDownSelectBuilding').onChange(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/LocationSelect/SelectFloor',
                            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'html'
                        })
                        .success(function (result) {
                            $('#showFloors').html(result);
                        })
                        .error(function (xhr, status) {
                            alert(status);
                        })
                    });
                </script>
                End Section
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="showFloors">

    </div>
```

Partial View:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>*Select the floor this item will move to:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-sm" type="button" id="dropDownSelectFloorMoveTo" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">

                <span class="selection"></span>
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labeledby="dropDownSelectFloorMoveTo">
                @For Each item In Model
                    Dim currentItem = item
                    @<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/LocationSelect/SelectFloor"
                                                >@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem)</a>
                    </li>
                Next
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
Public Class LocationSelectController
    Inherits Controller

    Private db As New MCSCInventoryModels

    ' GET: LocationSelect
    Function Index() As ActionResult

        Dim distinctBuildings = From Row In db.tblLocations
                                Select Row.Building
                                Distinct

        Return View(distinctBuildings)
    End Function

    ' GET: FloorS
    Function SelectFloor(ByVal selectedBuilding As String) As PartialViewResult

        Dim floorsInSelectedBuilding = From Row In db.tblLocations
                                       Where Row.Building = selectedBuilding
                                       Select Row.Floor
                                       Distinct

        Return PartialView(floorsInSelectedBuilding)
    End Function
End Class
```

Can you tell me why this ajax call opens the partial view in it's own page, instead of rendering it in the specified div?

**Update** I have checked the accepted answers to both of these questions and they have not solved the issue.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840516/why-partial-view-not-rendering-in-the-same-page-asp-net-mvc-4?rq=1)
and
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540745/why-does-partial-view-show-as-full-page-in-mvc-5-visual-studio-13?lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately what was causing this issue was my use of a non-traditional drop down.  To solve the problem I added a `class` to the `<a role="menuitem">` like so:

```
@<li role="presentation"><a class="ddlist" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"
                                >@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem)</a></li>
```

and then used:

```
$('.ddlist').click(function () {
```

to trigger the ajax call.

I also removed the `href="/LocationSelect/SelectFloor"` which was left over from the design phase and causing the partial view to open in it's own page when a selection was made and the ajax wasn't being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing the unobtrusive script in your layout page.

```html
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

refer to this question:

[Why does Partial View show as full page in MVC 5 Visual Studio 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540745/why-does-partial-view-show-as-full-page-in-mvc-5-visual-studio-13)

one more thing is to add the last (UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled) line to your config file (Web.Config):

```html
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
        <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Comment: I did not have unobtrusive added to the project.  I did add it, and configured it each way that was mentioned in those answers and I am still left with my partial opening it's own page.

Comment: And you are sure that ~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js is the correct path, refreshed / closed studio and browser to make sure it really does get loaded.

Comment: I am able to use their link in the 'view source' and see their proper files

Comment: updated the answer, please try the config file change. Also, can you place debugger, or alert into your success part of the ajax call, i'm interested what the result there looks like alert(result). Does the code come back to the function or...

Comment: added to config no change.  tested with alerts and there is an issue.  Changed `onChange` to `click` and get the proper result in terms of display.  So I'm going to need to figure out the proper command for when the drop down list value is selected

Comment: so it is being populated into the target div? not it's own page? with the dropdown you have to use var selected =  $(this).val(); to get the chosen item value, then pass it to your ajax call, catch the value in your controller to do business logic and return the partial view based on that value. i assume use this in the ajax call below datatype: data: JSON.stringify( {selectedBuilding : selected} );